# PlaneProjection is not working well in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, assemblies, namespaces, projection

in silverlight project using name attribute in planeprojection gives  Error 1 The type or namespace name 'PlaneProjection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

code i used for that

```
<Image Name="blabla.jpg" Height="200" Width="200" >
    <Image.Projection>
       <PlaneProjection Name="pp" />
    </Image.Projection>
</Image>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a strange error in that it appears to be complaining about the `PlaneProjection` itself but that could be a red-herring.

The xaml is not correct because the `PlaneProjection` does not have a `Name` property.  However you should be able to `x:Name`.  My guess is you are trying to ensure you have a field called `pp` that you can manipulator in code.  You can now use `pp` as a field in code or find the `PlaneProjection` using `FindName` on the control.

This is what I think your Xaml should look like:-

```
<Image x:Name="MyImage" Source="blabla.jpg" Height="200" Width="200" > 
    <Image.Projection> 
       <PlaneProjection x:Name="pp" /> 
    </Image.Projection> 
</Image>
```

TBH, I would simply access the projection as `MyImage.Projection` rather than add an x:Name to it.